# Workspaces are "blank" when selecting remote repos in Sourcetree

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

When adding a remote repository in Sourcetree from a Bitbucket account the dropdown to select which workspace has a line for each workspace and you can select them but the lines are blank.

[image: showing error with dark theme]

The same with the Light theme
[image: showing error with light theme]

I've tried reinstalling Sourcetree, including wiping user settings/config, to no avail.

These are the workspaces that I have on Bitbucket and are definitely the 2 things im choosing from in the dropdown.

[image: workspaces on my Bitbucket]

Also reporting this as a bug to Atlassian [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Workspaces-are-quot-blank-quot-when-selecting-remote-repos-in/qaq-p/1967986#M41171) but wondered if it's a config thing in Sourcetree/Bitbucket I've got wrong.